# Change Twitter Bootstrap button status to active in Button Group with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to set the status of a button to active based on the value of "OrderBy" with no results, I've tried all the Q/A in stackoverflow.

```
    <div class="btn-group col-md-offset-5" style="right: 12px !important;">
        <label class="btn btn-default" ng-class="'active':orderProp=='name'">
            <input type="radio" name="color" data-ng-model="orderProp" value="name"> Alphabetical
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default" ng-class="'active':orderProp=='price'">
            <input type="radio" name="color" data-ng-model="orderProp" value="price"> Price
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default" ng-class="'active':orderProp=='calorie'">
            <input type="radio" name="color" data-ng-model="orderProp" value="calorie"> Calorie
        </label>{{orderProp}}
    </div>
```

The value of orderProp is changing accordingly but dunno why the active class is not being applied.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `ng-class = "{'active' : (orderProp=='name')}"`

The directive operates in three different ways, depending on which of three types the expression evaluates to:

If the expression evaluates to a string, the string should be one or more space-delimited class names.

If the expression evaluates to an object, then for each key-value pair of the object with a truthy value the corresponding key is used as a class name.

If the expression evaluates to an array, each element of the array should either be a string as in type 1 or an object as in type 2. This means that you can mix strings and objects together in an array to give you more control over what CSS classes appear.

Comment: Why should anyone try this code? What does this code do? Please add an explanation **in the answer**.

Comment: Thank You..Worked on first hit..can you please explain the difference?

Comment: Thanks a lot. That also helped me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-class` takes a json string as the argument.

Try this - `ng-class="{'active':orderProp=='name'}"`